# Drawing by replacement and without

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am still studying statistics (almost done with the basics).

I read something interesting in a document from Berkeley:

"Since $\Bbb E[x] = \mu$, we say that the sample mean is an unbiased estimator of $\mu$. This assumes that the sam- ples are independent and all taken from the same distribution, or iid for “independent and identically dis-
tributed” (pronounced “eye-eye-dee”). This is a non-trivial assumption that is often wrong! For example, if you sample without replacement from a finite set, the distribution changes as you remove items."

Here is the link to the complete PDF: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~brewer/cs262b/Lec1-stats.pdf

This statement contradicts other references I found on the topic. It is my understanding that drawing with or without replacement should not change the equality $\Bbb E[x] = \mu$. It seems to me that if you have 100 items in your population and that your sample size is 10, then if you draw without replacement you will have 10 samples. Shouldn't the expectation of the samples be the population mean in this case. Shouldn't doing the same experiment with replacement this time, gives $\Bbb E[x] = \mu$ as the number of samples approaches infinity (and this is true whether the population is finite or infinite)?

Thank you.

EDIT: Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might just be a bit unclearly formulated. The unconditional mean, $E(X)$, is the same, but the *conditional* mean changes -- and that's what the lecturer must be referring to, since s/he's saying that you remove objects with no replacement.

As an example, the hypergeometric distribution has expectation $ \frac{nk}{N}$. If you start with 10 white balls in an urn containing 100 balls, the mean for one draw ($n=1$) is $\mu=\frac{10}{100}=\frac{1}{10}$. Let's say you draw one white ball and do not replace it. Then you have the expectation $\frac{9}{99}\neq \frac{1}{10}$. But this is not the unconditional expectation $E(X)$, as you are conditioning on removing one ball.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know about the concept of unconditional expectation. This is a great answer. Thank you.